# Remove duplicate lines without sorting and ignore case

Tags: bash, shell-script

So, let's say I want to remove duplicate lines without sorting, as in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532157/remove-duplicate-lines-without-sorting), but I also want to remove duplicate lines that aren't case sensitive without converting all the strings to uppercase or lowercase beforehand, and keep the first result's case. How can I do this?

Comment: Better show us a sample input and expected output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A variant of [the accepted solution in your reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11532197/4500798) will do this for you:

```
awk '!x[tolower($0)]++'
```

I’m assuming that “without converting all the strings to uppercase or lowercase beforehand” means without converting them before running the above, which would prevent keeping the case of the first result. This approach preserves the case of the first match:

```
$ awk '!x[tolower($0)]++' <<EOF
éCoLe
École
école
ÉCOLE
EOF
éCoLe
```